# Aspose Cells Setting Focus on Cell or Column when Opening Workbook

Tags: vb.net, aspose-cells

I am trying to set the focus on a certain column or cell when I open up my Spreadsheet after creating a document using Aspose Cells. The issue is that it hides/removes the first 30 plus columns. FirstVisibleColumn is not wroking. I have also tried to make cells active with no luck.

```
sheet.FirstVisibleColumn = sheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn
sheet.FirstVisibleRow = 0
```

[Screen shot of Excel Workbook showing that it opens to correct column, but  Columns before AO are missing/hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kkRB.jpg)

More than happy to post more code if needed, but don't think it is necessary for this question. Finally, https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Activating+Sheets+and+Activating+a+Cell+in+Worksheet does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the article given by you is working fine. I have attached the output Excel file generated by the code as well as the screenshot for your reference. Please remember, this code will only work when you have already set the license. It means, the code will work in **License Mode** and will not work in **Evaluation Mode**.

We have tested this issue in **Aspose.Cells for Java v17.10**.

Besides, you can further elaborate your issue so that we could understand it better and help you.

**Download Link**

- [Output Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o867sr3n0a8qyl/SO-47164585-Output%20Excell%20File.zip?dl=0)

**Screenshot**
[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose